# LocalDateTime JPA - Java 8

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, postgresql-9.4

When my fields were persited by JPA, at certain time it saves with date ad time correct and others, it not save, only a date is correct, but the time is zero (00:00:00).

Corretct: **13/11/2019 11:05:12**
Not Corretct: **13/11/2019 00:00:00**

My database is postgresql and my field is of type `timestamp`

At java class, my field is annotated like this:

```
@Column(name = "DAT_ACTION")
private LocalDateTime espDatAction;
```

I dont now what is happening, because the application's operation are the same and and has different behaviors

Comment: user @Temporal in a JPA which can be used to store in the database table on of the following column items:DATE (java.sql.Date),TIME (java.sql.Time),TIMESTAMP (java.sql.Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a LocalDate attribute in a DATE column or a LocalDateTime in a TIMESTAMP column, you need to define the mapping to java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp yourself. You can try to add something like below and restart the application, it should save correctly after it:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
 
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
     
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
    }
 
    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this way with JPA 2.2 new version

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime espDatAction;
```

Comment: This approach is for object serialization when I work with rest. I want to persist my date time into database. I believe that your suggestion, although it's good, not apply to my case.